# starting with eclipse for android development

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

hi i am a new developer for both java and android. i have installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers in my system(win 7, 32 bit). i cant find the Android SDK and AVD manager option in the windows list. I myself doubt whether i have installed a right one or not. In my programs file the eclipse location is been named as "eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32". Is it a right one which i have installed. pls help me...

Comment: What is your actual problem? Do Android projects work? Did you create an emulator in the AVD settings?

Comment: Do some reading: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: hi friends, actually i have following all the instructions in developer.android.com. The main thing is in Eclipse i have to select Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager, but in my window i dont have any Android SDK and AVD manager. Why this problem and how to solve this

Answer (score 2):

Simply installing the Helios IDE is not enough. Follow the install steps on [this page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

Comment: hi friends, actually i have following all the instructions in http://developer.android.com. The main thing is in Eclipse i have to select Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager, but in my window i dont have any Android SDK and AVD manager. Why this problem and how to solve this.

Comment: Did you [download the sdk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) ? If yes. did you install it ?

Comment: In addition to downloading and installing the SDK, did you install the ADT plugin for Eclipse?  Did you tell Eclipse where the SDK is located (Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location)?

Answer (score 2):

`Preferences>Android>SDK` location does not already exist in Eclipse.

First install [ADT Plugin](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) as a new software from `Help>Install New software`.